# Static cells: Content does not appear

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.2, storyboard

I simply want to have a static table View with items in it. I used Xcode 4.2 with storyboard for this task. So I created a TableView with a tableViewController (subclass UITableViewController). I defined the content as "Static Cells" and style "Grouped".

After that I put some lables and all those objects I want to have in those cells. I created Outlets in the tableViewController:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface tableviewcontroller : UITableViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmented;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *text;

@end
```

put some content in the cell-label:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.label1.text = @"This is a title";
    self.label2.text = @"Annika";
    self.imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"picture.jpg"];
}
```

After build and run, it doesn't show me any of the elements... what did I do wrong?

Left: In storyboard, right: In the simulator.
[image]

Comment: Did you put any information in the cells?

Comment: Yes, at least for the lables and the picture. (see above, I edited my question!) But although I wouldn't have put any information in the cells, it should at least show me the segmented control?

Comment: there must be a problem with the tableviewcontroller. I realized that my labels will be viewed when I don't have a controller. So maybe there must be a implicit declaration for the content in the tableviewcontroller.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For static table views, you must not implement any of the datasource methods. The base implementation of UITableViewController has its own versions of these methods which return the appropriate content by reading the storyboard file. The methods are those which provide the table content, e.g. numberOfRows, numberOfSections, heightForRow, cellForRow and so forth.

In your case, you'd implemented `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and returned empty cells each time. This meant the size of your cells was correct, but the content was gone.

Also, none of the outlets to content in your static table view will be set until *after* `[super viewWillAppear:animated]` has been called. They will still be nil at viewDidLoad, where you are calling them from, because the table view hasn't asked for any of it's content at that point.

Comment: okay, so I have to set all the outlets in `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`. Something like `[self setLabel1:nil];`? But not setting nil. If that's right, what do I have to write instead of `nil`? Sorry, I'm such a bloody beginner.

Comment: The code you have in the question is fine, it's just in the wrong place!

Comment: that's good to hear. I put the  `self.Label1.text = @"This is a title"; etc. ` now in every possible part... in `- (void)viewDidLoad , in - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`, in `- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` but it still doesn't want to be viewed :( I don't have enough knowledge to jugde where it should be put. That's maybe why I put the code randomly in every possible place.

Comment: If you're still seeing the cell outlines but no content, something is off with your view controller subclass or the connections. Make sure the delegate and datasource of the table are linked to the view controller, check with the debugger to see which methods are actually being called, and if all else fails, post your code to a pastebin or GitHub and put a link to it in the question. I've seen people do static tables where _nothing_ appears, but just to get the cell outlines with no content is a new one.

Comment: Put my code into pastebin. Actually the datasource (the outlets?) is linked to the view. http://pastebin.com/u/Kirinriki

Comment: It's like I said in the original answer. For static cells, you must not implement any of the data source methods, or this overrides the content in the storyboard. Delete your numberOfRows, numberOfSections and cellForRow method. For static cells, these are populated by the base implementation in UITableViewController.

Comment: thanks alot! I'm so sorry, I didn't get clearly what you meant at the beginning. But now it's clear.

Comment: Don't worry about it. I will add more explanation to the answer for future readers.

Comment: try setting content to statice instead of dynamic