# How to create a Custom UITableView with Sections and grouped cell?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am having a hard time to display a custom View manually designed in my storyboard:

[image]

I did not implement any delegate in my interface:

```
@interface SettingsViewController :  UIViewController

@end
```

But I made sure they everything else is hooked up in my inspector

[image]

Error is thrown:

> 2014-01-20 13:32:38.480 appadmin[8597:60b]
>   -[SettingsViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x166543c0 2014-01-20
>   13:32:38.483 anonymousalertsadmin[8597:60b] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[SettingsViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x166543c0'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x30fb5e83 0x3b3126c7 0x30fb97b7 0x30fb80af 0x30f06dc8 0x3380eb15 0x33810d79 0x33810cd1 0x338108cb
>   0x33813e53 0x3373a353 0x333c0943 0x333bc167 0x3374f231 0x33866a5d
>   0x338668ed 0x33865da5 0x33865c23 0x33865b2f 0x33930845 0x3376eda3
>   0x3376ed3f 0x339306fb 0x3376eda3 0x3376ed3f 0x3376ed13 0x3375a743
>   0x3376eda3 0x3376ed3f 0x3376ed13 0x3375a743 0x3376e75b 0x337321a1
>   0x30f80f69 0x30f7e8f7 0x30f7ec43 0x30ee9471 0x30ee9253 0x35c232eb
>   0x3379e845 0xd39a9 0x3b80bab7) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException

When I am implementing the missing method then they show as blank

I read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11240587/3205189) this is why I removed the delegate method numberOfRows and others.

These are static cells, so I should not have to worry about reusing them, I feel like they should be an easy way to do this. I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: If you are using the static cells. Remove the datasource connection from the IB. This connection makes the table view search for data in you view controller class.

Comment: @somexyz When I do this I no longer get the error, but nothing displays, just a blank view

Comment: Seems like you have deleted the methods only not the datasource connection. By this connection i mean the connection being shown in the inspector image posted in the question.

Comment: I know what u mean. It's still blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably your issue

```
@interface SettingsViewController :  UIViewController

@end
```

You cannot use UIViewController to achieve this you must use `UITableViewController`.

> These are static cells, so I should not have to worry about reusing them, I feel like they should be an easy way to do this. I am not sure what I am missing.

You are right, Static table cells don't need a data source. However, a static table view must be managed by a `UITableViewController`.

This is my observation from experience, I don't have any documentation to back up my answer.