# Cell content in a static tableview not showing

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a regular `ViewController` in which I have added a `tableView` that occupies a small portion of screen (as seen below). Because my `tableView` is static, I have not implemented any of the Tableview datasource methods as recommended in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238869/static-cells-content-does-not-appear) here. However, the content that I have put in in Storyboard is not showing up, and I am at a loss as to what else could be going on.

To illustrate, the below is what I have set up in Storyboard:

[image]

But this is is what shows in the simulator:

[image]

I have set `self.tableview.delegate = self` in `viewDidLoad`, as well as declaring my view controller to be a `<UITableViewDelegate>`. However, none of this has helped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Static cells work only with UITableViewControllers. They serve as a data source for the table view and are responsible for providing it with all those rows you nicely set up it the Interface Buider. I usually use a Container View in such situations. It is a view which displays the another view controller's view inside it. In your case this 'another controller' is a UITableViewController or the one, derived from it.

[image]

Comment: This approach requires NO no code, everything can be set up in the IB.