# ImageView is not displayed inside static table view cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiimageview, uikit

I have a static table view with `UITableViewController`. I add `UIImageView` to first cell and connect this `UIImageView` outlet to my custom `UITableViewController`.
Inside `viewWillAppear` after `super.viewWillAppear(animated)` I try to set image for image view, but it looks hidden. Only if I do this inside `viewDidAppear` my image is shown. I have no implemented methods from `UITableViewDelegate/DataSource` and my image view is always not hidden. If I call `reloadData()` nothing happens (it's useless for static tables).
I want my image set before `viewDidAppear`, so I don't want to see delay before my image is set.

```
class FPProfileViewController: UITableViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var userPhotoImageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        userPhotoImageView.image = //myImage
    }
}
```

It looks strange, in my other project the same algorithm works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for, had the same problem. It seems UIImageView's in a static table view cell need to be part of - (void) viewWillAppear - based on this answer : [Static cells: Content does not appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238869/static-cells-content-does-not-appear).

For my situation, it didn't help, I had to go straight in - (void) viewDidLoad.